# In Python OOP can you help me understand why does this code not work

Tags: python-3.x, oop

when I run this code I get an error message
"AttributeError: 'Acrobat' object has no attribute 'Stagename'"
This is an exam question and the code has been provided as an example answer.
I am not sure why it does not work or where my error is?

```
    def __init__(self, Firstname, Lastname, Stagename, SecondaryRole, Type):
        self.__FirstName = Firstname
        self.__LastName = Lastname
        self.__StageName = Stagename
        self.__SecondaryRole = SecondaryRole
        self.__PerfType = Type

    def EditSecondaryRole(self, NewRole):
        self.SecondaryRole = NewRole
        
    def EditStageName(self, NewStageName):
        self.StageName = NewStageName


class Acrobat(Performer):
    def __init__(self,Firstname, Lastname, Stagename, SecondaryRole, Fire):
        Performer.__init__(self, Firstname, Lastname, Stagename, SecondaryRole, "Acrobat")
        self.__UseFire = Fire

    def PerformerInfo(self):
        ReturnString = "%s (real name %s %s) is %s. " % (self. Stagename, self.Firstname,self. Lastname, Acrobat.PerfType)
        if(self.__UseFire):
            ReturnString = ReturnString + "Fire is part of %s's act. " % (self.Stagename)
        else:
            ReturnString = ReturnString + "Fire is not part of %s's act. " %(self.Stagename)
        ReturnString = ReturnString + "When not performing, %s is a %s" % (self.Stagename, self.SecondaryRole)
        return ReturnString


Acrobat1 = Acrobat("Alex","Tan","Amazing Alex","Popcorn Seller",True)

print(Acrobat1.PerformerInfo())
```

Comment: By giving all of `Performer`'s attributes names starting with two underscores, you made them private to that class.  Even subclasses cannot access them (without some trickery).  The class is basically unusable as written, since you cannot do anything with the data it contains.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - the code is the example so that's not good news if the provided example does not work.  I have removed the private __ attributes but I still get the same error message.

Comment: If the code you were given was using private attributes, then it must have also had public "getter" functions (that you seem to have left out) to allow code outside the class to make  use of those attributes.

Comment: Thanks again - I removed the private attributes and that works.  But the question asked for private attributes to be used.   I have included the whole answer provided.  Where would the getter methods go - in the Performer parent class?  I know what getter are but not sure how to use them in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help - this works but Im still not sure how to answer the question with private methods

```
    def __init__(self, Firstname, Lastname, Stagename, Secondaryrole, Type):
        self.Firstname = Firstname
        self.Lastname = Lastname
        self.Stagename = Stagename
        self.Secondaryrole = Secondaryrole
        self.PerfType = Type

    def EditSecondaryRole(self, NewRole):
        self.Secondaryrole = NewRole
        
    def EditStageName(self, NewStageName):
        self.Stagename = NewStageName


class Acrobat(Performer):
    def __init__(self,Firstname, Lastname, Stagename, Secondaryrole, Fire):
        Performer.__init__(self, Firstname, Lastname, Stagename, Secondaryrole, "Acrobat")
        self.__UseFire = Fire


    def PerformerInfo(self):
        ReturnString = "%s (real name %s %s) is %s. " % (self.Stagename, self.Firstname,self. Lastname, "Acrobat")
        if(self.__UseFire):
            ReturnString = ReturnString + "Fire is part of %s's act. " % (self.Stagename)
        else:
            ReturnString = ReturnString + "Fire is not part of %s's act. " %(self.Stagename)
        ReturnString = ReturnString + "When not performing, %s is a %s" % (self.Stagename, self.Secondaryrole)
        return ReturnString

Performer1 = Performer("Paul","Smith","Smithy","Greeter","Clown")
Acrobat1 = Acrobat("Alex","Tan","Amazing Alex","Popcorn Seller",False)

print(Acrobat1.PerformerInfo())
```